# Center Media div in a column using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have an html template page. In the template, I have a media object with a logo and a piece of text. How both items are in a column that is 5 wide. It is off center and aligned to the left. I want to take the media block and center it within the column no matter how big the column is (5,7,9,12). What is the best approach to do this. Here is the html code. I am using the latest version of bootstrap 3.3.7 and 4.0.0 beta.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="align-self-center mr-3 welcome-icon-size" src="{% static 'images/yap-logo-possible-1.png'%}" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h1 class="mt-0 welcome_title">Split Beta</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

here is the display:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are using bootstrap, just place `text-center` class into your `col-xl-5 col-lg-5` for aligning center the inner elements. You can use your own class `logo` for the inner elements styling.

```css
.logo {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 text-center">
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="align-self-center mr-3 welcome-icon-size" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <h1 class="mt-0 welcome_title">Split Beta</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```